# Proper way to create dynamic automatic billing method with paypal API?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I know this maybe a duplicate but due to the overwhelming amount of paypal APIs I am having a hard time finding a GOOD answer to my question.

I need to create variable monthly billing per user in PHP. The idea is that a user could sell a number of items with a total sum of sales at the end of the month *p*. So the billing would be something of the extent MY_PERCENTAGE_FEE * *p*. The user would then be sent an invoice, and a would be automatically billed via paypal for that amount.

Now, it would be SUPER great if this could be done by creating reoccurring billing and updating the amount at the end of the month. Is that possible? If not what would be the next best way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're creating recurring profiles with Payments Pro you can adjust those without any limits.  Unfortunately, with Express Checkout you're limited to raising the amount by only 20% every 180 days, so that doesn't normally work out very well.  You have a few options of how to get around that.

1) Utilize billing agreements with [Express Checkout](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf) and Reference Transactions.  This would allow you to run an authorization (or an original sale of some sort) for a payer and then from that point on you can use that transaction ID from the original transaction along with a new amount in the DoReferenceTransaction API.  Reference Transactions area available with Payments Pro by default, but if you want to use them with Express Checkout you'll need to get that specifically enabled on your account.

2) Use the [Preapproval API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/), which is part of the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) platform. This is similar to reference transactions except that you can create preapproved rules by which you can bill your payers at any time without further approval.  This would allow you to process payments for them at any time you need to and pull variable amounts accordingly.

3) Use the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/), which is also part of Adaptive Payments, with a split payment (parallel or chained) which would allow you to take your cut in real-time without the need to track balances and submit variable recurring payments.  Each time one of your customers is paid for their product/service, you would immediately be paid your share.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I did tons more research and found this to be the answer but forgot about the question :).